# cannot read property history because it's undefined but it is

Tags: reactjs, meteor, react-router, react-router-dom

I am getting the error cannot read property history but I defined it.

This used the work when I had it in main.jsx in my client folder but now it stops working.

The app file is in my imports folder.

```jsx
import { Router, Route, Switch, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import createBrowserHistory from "history/createBrowserHistory";

const history = createBrowserHistory();

// App component - represents the whole app
export class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">

        <Router history={history}>
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
            <Route
              path="/dashboard"
              render={() =>
                this.props.currentUser ? <Dashboard /> : <NoPermission />}
            />
            <Route path="/test" component={Test} />
            <Route component={NotFound} />
          </Switch>
        </Router>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

more info:

import createBrowserHistory from "history/createBrowserHistory";

within that file createBrowserHistory is the default export.

```
export.default = createBrowserHistory;
```

When trying BrowserRouter instead of router and deleting the history const and props I get following error in my console.

```
modules.js:26944 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'history' of undefined
    at Link.render (modules.js?hash=b38005f7c50b72cb1ea0945090b4ba307f31282f:26944)
    at modules.js?hash=b38005f7c50b72cb1ea0945090b4ba307f31282f:18399
    at measureLifeCyclePerf (modules.js?hash=b38005f7c50b72cb1ea0945090b4ba307f31282f:17679)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._renderValidatedComponentWithoutOwnerOrContext (modules.js?hash=b38005f7c50b72cb1ea0945090b4ba307f31282f:18398)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._renderValidatedComponent (modules.js?hash=b38005f7c50b72cb1ea0945090b4ba307f31282f:18425)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.performInitialMount (modules.js?hash=b38005f7c50b72cb1ea0945090b4ba307f31282f:17965)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent (modules.js?hash=b38005f7c50b72cb1ea0945090b4ba307f31282f:17861)
    at Object.mountComponent (modules.js?hash=b38005f7c50b72cb1ea0945090b4ba307f31282f:10622)
    at ReactDOMComponent.mountChildren (modules.js?hash=b38005f7c50b72cb1ea0945090b4ba307f31282f:16977)
    at ReactDOMComponent._createInitialChildren (modules.js?hash=b38005f7c50b72cb1ea0945090b4ba307f31282f:14176)
```

When using BrowserRouter in my main.jsx I can get it working. I can change URL's but the new views do not render. So I think there still is something wrong with the history. In this case I have not defined it but I am not receiving any errors. Any way how I can check or fix this?

```
import React from "react";
import { Meteor } from "meteor/meteor";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import "../imports/startup/accounts-config.js";

import App from "../imports/layouts/App.jsx";
import Test from "../imports/Test.jsx";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";

Meteor.startup(() => {
  render(
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>,
    document.getElementById("render-target")
  );
});
```

Going further on Kyle's answer I added withrouter to my test component.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { withRouter } from "react-router";

class Test extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    match: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    location: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    history: PropTypes.object.isRequired
  };

  render() {
    const { match, location, history } = this.props;

    return (
      <div>
        <p>This is a test</p>
        <p>
          You are now at {location.pathname}
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(Test);
```

I am using NavLinks to link to this route in my navigation bar component.

```
   <NavLink to="/test" activeClassName="active">
          Test
        </NavLink>
```

However clicking those links does not render the test page. (the address in the URL bar does change). When I press refresh in the browser the page loads and the location.pathname shows the proper location.

If I remove the withrouter the functionality is the same.

**I got it working by not using a component to nest the router in.**
If somebody can explain me why I would greatly appreciate it.

```
import Navbar from "../components/Navbar.jsx";
import AccountsUIWrapper from "../components/AccountsUIWrapper.jsx";

//import pages
import Home from "../pages/Home.jsx";
import Dashboard from "../pages/Dashboard.jsx";
import Test from "../Test.jsx";
import NotFound from "../pages/NotFound.jsx";
import NoPermission from "../pages/NoPermission.jsx";

let currentUser = Meteor.user();

const App = () =>
  <Router>
    <div>
      <Navbar currentUser={currentUser} />

      <AccountsUIWrapper />

      <p>
        {currentUser ? currentUser._id : "current user id not found"}
      </p>

      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
        <Route
          path="/dashboard"
          render={() => (currentUser ? <Dashboard /> : <NoPermission />)}
        />
        <Route path="/test" component={Test} />
        <Route component={NotFound} />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  </Router>;

export default App;
```

Comment: is createBrowserHistory the default export in history/createBrowserHistory?

Comment: Would need to see some structure - Specifically where is `history/createBrowserHistory` in relation to this file and as @zim said, is it the default export? (if not, wrap `createBrowserHistory` like this in imports `{ createBrowserHistory }`)

Comment: Like @zim and said, you need to check for the export in history/createBrowserHistory. 
OR
Instead of importing `Router`, import `BrowserRouter` and then you wouldn't need the history prop.

Comment: I checked and the answers are in the first post. The history file is in my node_modules folder.

Comment: @Christoph What version of react-router are you using?

Comment: @KyleRichardson from my package.json react-router-dom > 4.1.2

Comment: @Christoph if you make a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) with your code that you are asking for an explanation to as why it doesn't work, I will diagnose your issue.

Comment: @KyleRichardson I was sandboxing my code and got it working there. I noticed I keep my router in main.jsx and I have moved everything now to app.jsx. Now it works perfectly. I think in the future I should make a habit of first making something simple that works and then expanding the rest of the code. Either way thanks for the advice and getting me thinking.

Comment: @Christoph you're welcome! Glad you're making progress now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React Router 4 has history baked into it. You can see from the documentation for [BrowserRouter](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/BrowserRouter), [HashRouter](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/HashRouter), and [MemoryRouter](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/MemoryRouter) that there is no argument for `history`.

If you would like to access history in React Router v4 you should use the [withRouter](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter) HoC on the component that you wish to have access to it in. `withRouter` will make `({match, history, location })` available inside any component that it wraps.

As you can see from this line of code: `var _createBrowserHistory = require('history/createBrowserHistory');` which is line 13 in `BrowserRouter.js` and `HashRouter.js` history is already included for you. It is also included in the memory router on line 9 of `MemoryRouter.js`.

Try changing your import at the top to `import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";` and then remove `history={ history }` from `<Router />`.

EDIT: Please take a look at the documentation for React Router 4. Here is a [basic example](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/basic).

Here is a post of the code incase the link ever goes dead.

```
import React from 'react'
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Link
} from 'react-router-dom'

const BasicExample = () => (
  <Router>
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li><Link to="/">Home</Link></li>
        <li><Link to="/about">About</Link></li>
        <li><Link to="/topics">Topics</Link></li>
      </ul>

      <hr/>

      <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
      <Route path="/about" component={About}/>
      <Route path="/topics" component={Topics}/>
    </div>
  </Router>
)

const Home = () => (
  <div>
    <h2>Home</h2>
  </div>
)

const About = () => (
  <div>
    <h2>About</h2>
  </div>
)

const Topics = ({ match }) => (
  <div>
    <h2>Topics</h2>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <Link to={`${match.url}/rendering`}>
          Rendering with React
        </Link>
      </li>
      <li>
        <Link to={`${match.url}/components`}>
          Components
        </Link>
      </li>
      <li>
        <Link to={`${match.url}/props-v-state`}>
          Props v. State
        </Link>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <Route path={`${match.url}/:topicId`} component={Topic}/>
    <Route exact path={match.url} render={() => (
      <h3>Please select a topic.</h3>
    )}/>
  </div>
)

const Topic = ({ match }) => (
  <div>
    <h3>{match.params.topicId}</h3>
  </div>
)

export default BasicExample
```

Comment: Thanks but what I do not understand here is why would you use the router without history? From how I understand it linking does not work then. And how should I integrate this? (I am looking for it as we speak but some more info would be usefull)

Comment: Like I said, history is baked into react router 4, it's already included for you. It uses the history module internally.

Comment: @Christoph check my update. Linking is easy, just use a `<Link />` or `<NavLink />` component. You can so programmatically navigate with `history.pushState()` or `history.replaceState()`. You can access history as described in my post by using `withRouter`.

Comment: I added my test component as reference in the first post. It seems like the history push does not happen since refreshing the page does work.

Comment: I recreated the router using the code from react router instead of using a component. Now it works. Any idea what could be the reason or might this be a bug? Anyway thanks for getting me on the right track.